# Airflow 2.2.4 celery worker down with error...amqp.exceptions.PreconditionFailed: (0, 0): (406) PRECONDITION_FAILED -

Tags: airflow

One of our airflow 2.2.4 celery worker frequently getting down with below error.

worker logs showing only this much

```
amqp.exceptions.PreconditionFailed: (0, 0): (406) PRECONDITION_FAILED - delivery acknowledgement on channel 1 timed out. Timeout value used: 72000000 ms. This timeout value can be configured, see consumers doc guide to learn more
[2023-07-23 01:09:46,054: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-63] Task airflow.executors.celery_executor.execute_command[7ef05d9e-2e0f-46f1-bf82-d90e03d7fbb7] succeeded in 7.021644219756126s: None
[2023-07-23 01:11:32,858: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-7] Task airflow.executors.celery_executor.execute_command[352d1160-2099-4b99-9d74-72d3ed7f2b9f] succeeded in 692.3410388156772s: None
[2023-07-23 01:11:52,840: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-3] Task airflow.executors.celery_executor.execute_command[b043f3a7-da3d-4ad9-be3a-cb9af243f1ad] succeeded in 523.7127616927028s: None
```

changes rebbitMQ Consumer timeout option but same problem